# Sending values from Js to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I am asking for user's location on page loading and set it to hidden fields and try to read it from their to php. The JS code works but when I echo it to php, its showing null and after printing 'value is submitted' it keeps reloading the whole page.

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById(\"latitude\");
    var y = document.getElementById(\"longitude\");
    var a;
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else
        {
            x.innerHTML = \"Geolocation is not supported by this browser.\";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        x.value = position.coords.latitude; 
        y.value= position.coords.longitude;
        submitform();
    }
    function submitform()
    {
        document.forms[\"locform\"].submit();
        console.log(\"Value is sumitted\");
    }
    getLocation();
    </script>

<form action='abc.com/list' id='locform' method='get'>
    <input type='hidden' id='latitude' name='latitude'>
    <input type='hidden' id='longitude' name='longitude'>
</form>

$users_postal=$_GET['latitude'];
echo($users_postal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your javascript code executed before the page loaded. You must wait for all HTML load then run your js code.

You can achieve that by adding change form and script tag positions. Excatly write your js after HTML code.

```
<form action='abc.com/list' id='locform' method='get'>
   <input type='hidden' id='latitude' name='latitude'>
   <input type='hidden' id='longitude' name='longitude'> 
</form>
<script>
   // you js code here
</script>

/then write PHP code
$users_postal=$_GET['latitude'];
echo($users_postal);
```

Comment: can you share your code state with me after my answer? please send me it with pastebin.com